# Strange topology buggy vertex

Tags: vertices

This is my first post on Blender SE so please be patient with me.

I followed a Chair tutorial by Blender Guru on youtube. However, after all is done I have this "dang" vertex where topology goes heywire and for the love of god, I cannot find the problem with it.

[image]

(1) Vertexes are not duplicated. I tried both merging by distance and moving it.
(2) Normals are not flipped.

[image]

[image]

Please tell me either what is wrong with it, or how to fix it, or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wow I managed to fix it, hours after strugging with it, but a minute after posting the question. I still dont understand how it happened but here it is:

I noticed the leg had 2 faces on 3 sides but only 1 face on the 4th side. So... I removed the face and filled two new faces in its place. It solved the problem.

[image]